# How to upload images from a folder one by one in specific order?

Tags: python, tweepy

I'm making a twitter bot that uploads images from a specific folder one by one. How can I do this? The code I am using is:

```
import tweepy
from tweepy.streaming import Stream
from tweepy import Stream

consumer_key = 'XXXX'
consumer_secret = 'XXXX'
access_token = 'XXXX'
access_token_secret = 'XXXX'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit = True)

def upload_media(text, filename):
    media = api.media_upload(filename)
    text = filename.split(".")[0].split("\\")[-1]
    api.update_status(text, media_ids = [media.media_id_string])

upload_media('','World is amazing.jpg')
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: why did you tag OpenCV? I've untagged OpenCV and both version-specific python tags.

Comment: what is the problem? You can use `os.listdir()` or `glob.glob()` to get filenames in folder. And later you can use `for`-loop to run `upload_media()` with every file separatelly. But with `os.listdir()` you may have to remeber to add folder to filename to access file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like `os.listdir()` or `glob.glob` on the path of the folder to get the contents of said folder, then sort by the file extension for your images and then sort said list of files in the order that you want to.

```
import tweepy
import glob

from tweepy.streaming import Stream
from tweepy import Stream

consumer_key = 'XXXX'
consumer_secret = 'XXXX'
access_token = 'XXXX'
access_token_secret = 'XXXX'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit = True)

def upload_media(text, filename):
    media = api.media_upload(filename)
    text = filename.split(".")[0].split("\\")[-1]
    api.update_status(text, media_ids = [media.media_id_string])


pattern = "./*.jpg" # Example, will return all jpgs in working directory.
for file in glob.glob(pattern):
    upload_media('', file)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When posting an answer, you should include a good, simple, illustrative code example, not just outline a series of steps that possibly require further requests for clarification from the asker.  You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Could you please write a simple code for that? I am very new to python and I can't figure out how to do it as you say.

Comment: See the edit on my answer, not entirely sure how you want to sort the files but this is one way to sort by a pattern and path. If you need to sort the files themselves you can take the list of files produced by `glob.glob` and sort them in the way you see fit and then put that into the for loop.